# How to define multiple subsections for methods with Pod::Weaver?

Tags: perl, methods, documentation, dist-zilla

I have some Moose classes that define several small groups of related methods. I would like to make these groups obvious in the package POD.

I use `Dist::Zilla` and `Pod::Weaver` with the `=method` command. Is it possible to insert some `=head2-like` commands between my `=method` commands to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a post on how I did it for [Redis::Client](https://metacpan.org/module/Redis%3a%3aClient) here: [Falling in Love with Pod::Weaver](http://friedo.com/blog/2011/11/falling-in-love-with-podweaver).

The simplest thing to do is add custom `Collect` directives to your `weaver.ini` and organize your methods by giving each type a different custom POD command, like so:

```
[Collect / FOO METHODS]
command = foo_method

[Collect / BAR METHODS]
command = bar_method

[Collect / BAZ METHODS]
command = baz_method
```

Then write your POD like this

```
=foo_method blah blah
```

and Weaver will automatically collect them under their own `=head1`.

If you want to do something more complicated than that, you can write your own Pod::Weaver plugin. The gist is to search through the parsed POD for a custom command name and transform them by returning [Pod::Elemental](https://metacpan.org/module/Pod%3a%3aElemental) objects. Here's the plugin I wrote:

```
package Pod::Weaver::Plugin::RedisLinks;

# ABSTRACT: Add links to Redis documentation

use Moose;
with 'Pod::Weaver::Role::Transformer';

use Data::Dumper;
use Scalar::Util 'blessed';
use aliased 'Pod::Elemental::Element::Pod5::Ordinary';

sub transform_document {
    my ( $self, $doc ) = @_;

    my @children = $doc->children;

    my @new_children;
    foreach my $child( @{ $children[0] } ) {
        if ( $child->can( 'command' )
             && $child->command =~ /^(?:key|str|list|hash|set|zset|conn|serv)_method/ ) {
            my $meth_name = $child->content;
            $meth_name =~ s/^\s*?(\S+)\s*$/$1/;

            my $cmd_name = uc $meth_name;
            $cmd_name =~ tr/_/ /;

            my $link_name = $meth_name;
            $link_name =~ tr/_/-/;

            my $new_para = Ordinary->new(
                content => sprintf 'Redis L<%s|%s> command.',
                           $cmd_name, 'http://redis.io/commands/' . $link_name );

            push @new_children, $child, $new_para;
            next;
        }

        push @new_children, $child;
    }

    $doc->children( \@new_children );
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

1;
```

The `transform_document` method gets passed the parsed document as a parameter. It then goes through the top-level commands looking for elements labeled `/^(?:key|str|list|hash|set|zset|conn|serv)_method/`, munges the name a bit, and then builds a new POD paragraph containing the formatted POD content that I want.

Comment: Thank you for your fast and helpful answer, friedo! Right now, the first approach works well enough for me but I appreciate the possibilities of the second one.

Comment: No problem - have fun with Weaver. It's a really great tool.